# Mat Dialog media query properties?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-dialog component like this :

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(VerifyEmailComponent, {
  width: '100%',
  maxWidth: '100vw',
  data: {
    password: storedPassword,
    email,
    code
  },
  panelClass: 'modal-background'
});
```

Is it possible to add a different width and maxWidth based on screen size?
Also
is .resetProperties() the same thing as .close() property in material angular?
Thanks